# Dart test cannot access local variables

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart

Im trying to write some dart unit tests and can not figure out how to get `setUp()` to run. Tried it with both flutter_test.dart and test.dart. Adding a Breakpoint and debugging the test shows that `setUp()` is not being run.

Versions:

```
Flutter 2.3.0-2.0.pre.79 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision b3f7ebe069 (4 days ago) • 2021-05-08 08:54:02 +0800
Engine • revision f57e986aa8
Tools • Dart 2.14.0 (build 2.14.0-74.0.dev)

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  test: ^1.16.8
```

Following the readme for [test package](https://pub.dev/packages/test) and also [Shailen Tuli's blog](https://shailen.github.io/blog/2012/11/21/using-setup-in-your-dart-tests/) I have came up with this test

```
// import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

void main() {
  int int1;
  int int2;

  setUp(() {
    int1 = 1;
    int2 = 2;
  });

  test(
    'Check int1 and int2',
    () {
      print(int1);
      print(int2);
    },
  );
}
```

Error output is `The non-nullable local variable 'int1' must be assigned before it can be used. Try giving it an initializer expression, or ensure that it's assigned on every execution path.`

Not sure why it is not running. Tried adding `this.` in front and it threw more errors.

Comment: In the future, it would be helpful if you listed what the errors were.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import 'package:test/test.dart';

void main() {
  late int int1;
  late int int2;

  setUp(() {
    int1 = 1;
    int2 = 2;
  });

  test(
    'Check int1 and int2',
    () {
      print(int1);
      print(int2);
    },
  );
}
```

Null safety. RIP. Add [`late`](https://codewithandrea.com/videos/dart-null-safety-ultimate-guide-non-nullable-types/#the-late-keyword) keyword to initialize a variable when it is first read, rather than when it's created.

Comment: This worked for my code !!